# SQL query day wise not returning the correct result

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL script when running for single day is returning the correct result, but when running with condition to get the output for in between 30 days of data in script, I'm getting an incorrect result.

```
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP, SUM(fs) AS "fs" 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP), 'MM/DD/YY') AS "TIMESTAMP",
         COUNT(UNIQUE A.ID) AS "fs" 
     FROM 
         (SELECT * 
          FROM ag_se se 
          WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20')
            AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN (sysdate-30) AND (sysdate -1) 

          UNION ALL 

          SELECT * 
          FROM ag_sw sw 
          WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
            AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN (sysdate-30) AND (sysdate -1)

          UNION ALL

          SELECT * 
          FROM ag_mw mw 
          WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
            AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN (sysdate-30) AND (sysdate -1)

          UNION ALL

          SELECT * 
          FROM ag_w w 
          WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20')
            AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN (sysdate-30) AND (sysdate -1)

          UNION ALL

          SELECT *
          FROM ag_bl bl 
          WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20')
            AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN (sysdate-30) AND (sysdate -1)) A, aglogin B 
    WHERE 
        A.EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
        AND B.AGENTROLE IN ('FS_SW_EC', 'FS_SE_EC', 'FS_W_EC', 'FS_MW_EC')
        AND TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN (sysdate-30) AND (sysdate -1) 
        AND A.ID = B.ID 
        AND TRUNC(B.LOGINLOGOUTTIME) BETWEEN (sysdate-30) AND (sysdate -1)
    GROUP BY 
        B.AGENTROLE, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP), 'MM/DD/YY')) 
GROUP BY 
    TIMESTAMP;
```

But when running with below condition  output is correct :-

```
SELECT 
    TIMESTAMP, SUM(fs) AS "fs" 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP), 'MM/DD/YY') AS "TIMESTAMP", 
         COUNT(UNIQUE A.ID) AS "fs" 
     FROM 
         (SELECT * 
          FROM ag_se se 
          WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20')
            AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) = TRUNC(sysdate-30) 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT * 
          FROM ag_sw sw 
          WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
            AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) = TRUNC(sysdate-30) 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT * 
          FROM ag_mw mw 
          WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
            AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) = TRUNC(sysdate-30) 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT * 
          FROM ag_w w 
          WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
            AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) = TRUNC(sysdate-30) 
          UNION ALL 
          SELECT * 
          FROM ag_bl bl 
          WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
            AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) = TRUNC(sysdate-30)) A, aglogin B  
      WHERE 
          A.EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
          AND B.AGENTROLE IN ('FS_SW_EC', 'FS_SE_EC', 'FS_W_EC', 'FS_MW_EC') 
          AND TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP) = TRUNC(sysdate-30) 
          AND A.ID = B.ID 
          AND TRUNC(B.LOGINLOGOUTTIME) BETWEEN (TRUNC(sysdate-30)) AND (sysdate -1) 
      GROUP BY 
          B.AGENTROLE, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP), 'MM/DD/YY')) 
GROUP BY 
    TIMESTAMP;
```

My query is how can we get the output in a script for last 30 days as running individually query will take more time.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP,SUM(fs) AS "fs" FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP), 'MM/DD/YY') AS 
"TIMESTAMP", COUNT(UNIQUE A.ID) AS "fs" FROM ( SELECT * FROM ag_se se WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20')
AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP)  between (sysdate-30) and (sysdate -1) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ag_sw sw 
WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between (sysdate-30) and (sysdate -1) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ag_mw mw 
WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between (sysdate-30) and (sysdate -1) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ag_w w 
WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between (sysdate-30) and (sysdate -1) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ag_bl bl 
WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between (sysdate-30) and (sysdate -1)) A, aglogin B WHERE A.EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
AND B.AGENTROLE IN ('FS_SW_EC','FS_SE_EC','FS_W_EC','FS_MW_EC') AND TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP) between (sysdate-30) and (sysdate -1) 
AND A.ID =B.ID AND TRUNC(B.LOGINLOGOUTTIME) between  (sysdate-30) and (sysdate -1) GROUP BY B.AGENTROLE, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP), 'MM/DD/YY')) 
GROUP BY TIMESTAMP;
```

updated the query with having same result.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP,SUM(fs) AS "fs" FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP), 'MM/DD/YY') AS 
"TIMESTAMP", COUNT(UNIQUE A.ID) AS "fs" FROM ( SELECT * FROM ag_se se WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20')
AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP)  between trunc(sysdate-30) and trunc(sysdate -1) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ag_sw sw 
WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between trunc(sysdate-30) and trunc(sysdate -1) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ag_mw mw 
WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between trunc(sysdate-30) and trunc(sysdate -1) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ag_w w 
WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between trunc(sysdate-30) and trunc(sysdate -1) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ag_bl bl 
WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between  trunc(sysdate-30) and trunc(sysdate -1)) A, aglogin B WHERE A.EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
AND B.AGENTROLE IN ('FS_SW_EC','FS_SE_EC','FS_W_EC','FS_MW_EC') AND TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP) between trunc(sysdate-30) and trunc(sysdate -1) 
AND A.ID =B.ID AND TRUNC(B.LOGINLOGOUTTIME) between  trunc(sysdate-30) and trunc(sysdate -1) GROUP BY B.AGENTROLE, TO_CHAR(TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP), 'MM/DD/YY')) 
GROUP BY TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: from the query from last 30 days data above how can i get the correct result.

Comment: nobody knows your data, so we can't debug results

Comment: See how much easier it is to read that first query now? Now go make the others look the same. You'll be waaay more likely to get a good answer if you do.

Comment: Also the `A, B WHERE` join syntax has been obsolete for **more than 30 years** now. Don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be caused by conditions (in your "incorrect" query) where you are comparing Trunc(TIMESTAMP) with period  sysdate-30 and sysdate-1. That is TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) is a date at 00:00:00 and sysdate has a timepart contained (-30 and -1 also). The "correct" query is comparing TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) with TRUNC(SYSDATE) so there is a datepart without timepart on both sides.

try to change your "incorrect" query conditions to:

```sql
...
    TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between TRUNC(sysdate-30) and TRUNC(sysdate -1)
...
```

... the same problem here...

```sql
WHERE   A.EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND 
        B.AGENTROLE IN ('FS_SW_EC','FS_SE_EC','FS_W_EC','FS_MW_EC') AND 
        TRUNC(A.TIMESTAMP) between (sysdate-30) and (sysdate -1) AND --  <----
        A.ID =B.ID AND 
        TRUNC(B.LOGINLOGOUTTIME) between  (sysdate-30) and (sysdate -1)   --  <----
```

With no sample data provided it is hard to tell more but try to analyze the sample below where it is obvious that, in border cases, you could got different matches (IS_BETWEEN and IS_BETWEEN_TRUNCED columns)

```sql
WITH
    test AS
        ( Select 1 "ID", To_TimeStamp('2024-02-29 11:12:13', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "TS" From Dual )
Select  ID, TS, 
        TRUNC(TS) "TS_DATE", 
        To_Char(TRUNC(TS), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "TS_CHAR", To_Char(SYSDATE-4, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "SYSDT", 
        Case When TRUNC(TS) Between SYSDATE - 4 And SYSDATE - 1 Then 'YES' Else 'NO' End "IS_BETWEEN",
        To_Char(TRUNC(SYSDATE-4), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "TRUNCSYSDT" , 
        Case When TRUNC(TS) Between TRUNC(SYSDATE - 4) And TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) Then 'YES' Else 'NO' End "IS_BETWEEN_TRUNCED"
From    test
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
        ID TS                          TS_DATE  TS_CHAR             SYSDT               IS_BETWEEN TRUNCSYSDT          IS_BETWEEN_TRUNCED
---------- --------------------------- -------- ------------------- ------------------- ---------- ------------------- ------------------
         1 29.02.24 11:12:13,000000000 29.02.24 2024-02-29 00:00:00 2024-02-29 17:24:58 NO         2024-02-29 00:00:00 YES                */
```

NOTE:
Use **join on** sintax instead of listing tables combined with where conditions which is not considered as good practice for 30+ years...

***Just a blind guess:***
If you need count of distinct IDs per day in a period try it like below:

```sql
SELECT  TO_CHAR(A.TS, 'MM/DD/YY') AS "TIMESTAMP", 
        COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID) AS "fs" 
FROM    (   SELECT  ID, EVENTID, TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) "TS" 
            FROM    ag_se se 
            WHERE   EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND 
                    TRUNC(TIMESTAMP)  between TRUNC(sysdate-30) and TRUNC(sysdate -1) 
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT  ID, EVENTID, TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) 
            FROM    ag_sw sw 
            WHERE   EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND 
                    TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between TRUNC(sysdate-30) and TRUNC(sysdate -1) 
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT  ID, EVENTID, TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) 
            FROM    ag_mw mw 
            WHERE   EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND 
                    TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between TRUNC(sysdate-30) and TRUNC(sysdate -1) 
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT  ID, EVENTID, TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) 
            FROM    ag_w w 
            WHERE   EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND 
                    TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between TRUNC(sysdate-30) and TRUNC(sysdate -1) 
        UNION ALL 
            SELECT  ID, EVENTID, TRUNC(TIMESTAMP)
            FROM    ag_bl bl 
            WHERE   EVENTID IN ('AS20') AND 
                    TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between TRUNC(sysdate-30) and TRUNC(sysdate -1)
        ) A 
INNER JOIN  aglogin B ON(B.ID = A.ID)
WHERE       B.AGENTROLE IN ('FS_SW_EC','FS_SE_EC','FS_W_EC','FS_MW_EC') AND 
            TRUNC(B.LOGINLOGOUTTIME) between  TRUNC(sysdate-30) and TRUNC(sysdate -1) 
GROUP BY    TO_CHAR(A.TS, 'MM/DD/YY')
```

Comment: tried  with TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) between TRUNC(sysdate-30) and TRUNC(sysdate -1) having same result, is anything in main script query to change anything.

Comment: @bp_db Sorry, but it is hard to tell without some sample data, table structure and column datatypes. It would be just guessing. We don't even know what is "correct" or "not correct"

Comment: @bp_db ... did you change the same in outer WHERE clause - just added it to answer?

Comment: yes changed in outer where caluse also

Comment: is there any other way i can get the count for last 30 days in script.

Comment: @bp_db Why do you need grouping by B.AGENTROLE - it is already filtered by Where clause and not selected anywhere - might be that for 1 day you have limited AGENTROLES (maybe even just 1) than in 30 days period...

Comment: Since the query is looking at a range, even better if we don't use `TRUNC` on the original timestamp here at all, since that will break index use.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That is true, but he asks for distinct IDs per DATE - per timestamp would probably result as 1

Comment: @bp_db ... addded a blind guess

Comment: @dr He will need to truncate the date for the group by, but it will still be better to avoid it for the where clause.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yes, that is right. Do you know the role of Group By AGENTROLE !?

Comment: No idea. But if nothing else the OP should use your revised query as the new starting point, rather than jumbled wall of text he's shown so far.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Combined with your no BETWEEN no TRUNC(TIMESTAMP) in Unioned data

Answer (score 0):

When querying for a date range, for best results there are a couple things you should always try to do:

1. Avoid changing the original column value. This *breaks index use* for the query, since you are not longer using the same values stored in the index
2. Avoid `BETWEEN`, and instead use two comparisons forming a "half open" range with an exclusive upper bound for the day after the range.

In short, these comparisons:

```
TRUNC(TIMESTAMP)  between (sysdate-30) and (sysdate -1)
```

should actually look like this:

```
TIMESTAMP >= trunc(sysdate)-30 and TIMESTAMP < trunc(sysdate)
```

This will tend to perform **waaaay** better, and may also help get more accurate results.

There are some other issues in the code, as well. I don't see places where they'd cause inaccuracies, but it may help to post what the query should look like:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP,SUM(fs) AS "fs" 
FROM (
    select to_char(trunc(a.timestamp), 'MM/DD/YY') as "TIMESTAMP"
        , count(unique a.id) as "fs" 
    from ( 
        SELECT ID, EVENTID, TIMESTAMP
        FROM ag_se se 
        WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20')
            AND TIMESTAMP >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-30 and TIMESTAMP < TRUNC(SYSDATE) 

        UNION ALL 

        SELECT ID, EVENTID, TIMESTAMP
        FROM ag_sw sw 
        WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
            AND TIMESTAMP >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-30 and TIMESTAMP < TRUNC(SYSDATE)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT ID, EVENTID, TIMESTAMP
        FROM ag_mw mw 
        WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20') 
            AND TIMESTAMP >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-30 and TIMESTAMP < TRUNC(SYSDATE)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT ID, EVENTID, TIMESTAMP
        FROM ag_w w 
        WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20')
            AND TIMESTAMP >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-30 and TIMESTAMP < TRUNC(SYSDATE)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT ID, EVENTID, TIMESTAMP
        FROM ag_bl bl 
        WHERE EVENTID IN ('AS20')
            AND TIMESTAMP >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)-30 and TIMESTAMP < TRUNC(SYSDATE)
    ) a
    inner join aglogin b on a.ID = b.ID
    where b.agentrole in ('FS_SW_EC','FS_SE_EC','FS_W_EC','FS_MW_EC')
        and b.loginouttime >= trunc(sysdate)-30 and b.loginouttime < trunc(sysdate)
    group by b.agentrole, trunc(a.timestamp)
)  T
GROUP BY TIMESTAMP;
```

---

A note on casing: when there are multiple levels of nesting like this, my own practice breaks somewhat from the common UPPERCASE convention for keywords. Instead, I deliberately alternate casing between nesting levels, to help me see what code is supposed to belong with which level. I find this helps when reading a query later, as well as with spotting errors.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to `GROUP BY` once to get the totals (rather than aggregating twice) and on `timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30 AND timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)` (which will allow you to use an index on the `timestamp` column):

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(timestamp), 'MM/DD/YY') AS timestamp,
       COUNT(*) AS fs
FROM   (
  SELECT a.timestamp
  FROM   ag_se a
         INNER JOIN aglogin l
         ON (a.id = l.id)
  WHERE  a.timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
  AND    a.timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  AND    a.event_id  =  'AS20'
  AND    l.agentrole       =  'FS_SE_EC'
  AND    l.loginlogouttime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
  AND    l.loginlogouttime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
UNION ALL
  SELECT a.timestamp
  FROM   ag_sw a
         INNER JOIN aglogin l
         ON (a.id = l.id)
  WHERE  a.timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
  AND    a.timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  AND    a.event_id  =  'AS20'
  AND    l.agentrole       =  'FS_SW_EC'
  AND    l.loginlogouttime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
  AND    l.loginlogouttime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
UNION ALL
  SELECT a.timestamp
  FROM   ag_mw a
         INNER JOIN aglogin l
         ON (a.id = l.id)
  WHERE  a.timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
  AND    a.timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  AND    a.event_id  =  'AS20'
  AND    l.agentrole       =  'FS_MW_EC'
  AND    l.loginlogouttime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
  AND    l.loginlogouttime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
UNION ALL
  SELECT a.timestamp
  FROM   ag_w a
         INNER JOIN aglogin l
         ON (a.id = l.id)
  WHERE  a.timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
  AND    a.timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  AND    a.event_id  =  'AS20'
  AND    l.agentrole       =  'FS_W_EC'
  AND    l.loginlogouttime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
  AND    l.loginlogouttime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
)
GROUP BY TRUNC(timestamp)
```

or:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(timestamp),
       COUNT(*) AS fs
FROM   (
         SELECT id, timestamp, 'FS_SE_EC' AS agentrole
         FROM   ag_se
         WHERE  timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
         AND    timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
         AND    event_id  =  'AS20'
       UNION ALL
         SELECT id, timestamp, 'FS_SW_EC' AS agentrole
         FROM   ag_sw
         WHERE  timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
         AND    timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
         AND    event_id  =  'AS20'
       UNION ALL
         SELECT id, timestamp, 'FS_MW_EC' AS agentrole
         FROM   ag_mw
         WHERE  timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
         AND    timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
         AND    event_id  =  'AS20'
       UNION ALL
         SELECT id, timestamp, 'FS_W_EC' AS agentrole
         FROM   ag_w a
         WHERE  a.timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
         AND    a.timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
         AND    a.event_id  =  'AS20'
       ) a
       INNER JOIN aglogin l
       ON (   a.id        = l.id
          AND a.agentrole = l.agentrole)
WHERE  l.loginlogouttime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
AND    l.loginlogouttime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY TRUNC(timestamp)
```

or:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(timestamp),
       COUNT(*) AS fs
FROM   (
         SELECT id, event_id, timestamp, 'FS_SE_EC' AS agentrole
         FROM   ag_se
       UNION ALL
         SELECT id, event_id, timestamp, 'FS_SW_EC' AS agentrole
         FROM   ag_sw
       UNION ALL
         SELECT id, event_id, timestamp, 'FS_MW_EC' AS agentrole
         FROM   ag_mw
       UNION ALL
         SELECT id, event_id, timestamp, 'FS_W_EC' AS agentrole
         FROM   ag_w a
      ) a
      INNER JOIN aglogin l
      ON (   a.id        = l.id
         AND a.agentrole = l.agentrole)
WHERE  a.timestamp >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
AND    a.timestamp <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    a.event_id  =  'AS20'
WHERE  l.loginlogouttime >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 30
AND    l.loginlogouttime <  TRUNC(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY TRUNC(timestamp)
```